# how to use csrf token in Django integrated with vuejs using Django webpack loader?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, csrf, django-csrf

I am using Vuejs as frontend and Django rest framework as backend, I have some confusions how to use csrf token, my question has 2 part, first I write my configurations.
first as [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/) stated, "If your view is not rendering a template containing the `csrf_token` template tag, Django might not set the CSRF token cookie. This is common in cases where forms are dynamically added to the page. To address this case, Django provides a view decorator which forces setting of the cookie: `ensure_csrf_cookie()`", so this is my view that renders the page which loads webpack bundles.

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def main_view(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

and again as Django documentation I used below configuration to send csrf token along with Axios request.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

//axios request
async createFromCSV(token, data) {
    const options = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "X-CSRFToken": data.headers["csrftoken"]
      }

      // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    };
    return await axios.post(`${CREATE_FROM_CSV}`, data.data_, options);
  }
```

and at the end this is the view that should handle the post request( I omitted none relevant codes)

```
@requires_csrf_token
@api_view(['POST'])
@c_login_required()
def create_from_csv(request):
    if 'data_' in request.data:
        return JsonResponse({})
    else:
        raise MyValidationError({
                'message': 'اطلاعات ورودی درست نیست!!'
            })
```

so this is my questions:
1- the first problem is no matter what is the value of csrftoken or even if csrftoken header exist or not the request get through without any error, I even used postman for double check and send the request without any csrf token header but didn't get any error, why `@requires_csrf_token` does not work?
2- as stated above I used the Django documentation guide to get back token from html page, when I was checking request I noticed another cookie In request every time that its value was exactly the same as the token that I retrieved manually, how this csrftoken have been set automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer , I searched a lot but I couldn't find a place with proper description of using csrf in Django rest framework integrated with single page applications like react and vuejs, so I first answer my question and then write down the whole configuration.
the answer for first part of my question is that you should use `@csrf_protect` decorator instead of `@requires_csrf_token` because even though `@requires_csrf_token` works similarly to csrf_protect, but never rejects an incoming request.
although I fixed this but my request were processing without any csrf token, there was another problem and it was as [DRF documentation stated](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication), "CSRF validation in REST framework works slightly differently to standard Django due to the need to support both session and non-session based authentication to the same views. This means that only authenticated requests require CSRF tokens, and anonymous requests may be sent without CSRF tokens. This behaviour is not suitable for login views, which should always have CSRF validation applied", so anonymous request does not require csrf token, all I had to do was place `@api_view` decorator above `@csrf_protect` to authenticate user first and it solve this problem.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_protect
@c_login_required()
def create_from_csv(request):
    if 'data_' in request.data:
        return JsonResponse({})
    else:
        raise MyValidationError({
                'message': 'اطلاعات ورودی درست نیست!!'
            })
```

for the second part of my question you just had to retrieve token as above and then send the token in request header  `"X-CSRFToken": yourcsrftoken`

in summary:
1- use `@ensure_csrf_cookie` on the view that renders the page which request comes from, This decorator forces a view to send the csrf cookie.
2- retrieve the token as above and send the token along post request in request header with the this key: `X-CSRFToken`.
3- use `@csrf_protect` on the view that handles the post request after authenticating user because in Django rest frame work anonymous users doesn't require a token